# iOS AutoLayout - Button moves when app is launched

Tags: ios, autolayout

I will try to describe this issue--never seen this behavior before.

I have a button that moves from the right of the app's screen to the middle when the app launches on the simulator or actual device. I want it to always be in the middle (where it moves to).

Basically, it moves from one position on the parent view to another position (I want it to ALWAYS be in the position defined by the constraints)

How do I accomplish this?

Here are images to show the behavior and the constraints:

[Button is on the right, higher up; then fades out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qN4kG.png)

[Button fades in to the bottom, centered position (correct per constraints listed below)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2qlU.png)

Button constraints:

1. Button.centerX = centerX (center the button to the container's horizontal center)
2. Bottom Layout Guilde.top = Button.bottom + 112 (anchor the button to the bottom of the app regardless of screen size or orientation).

Comment: If you can post a sample project to github, it will be much easier for us to help you with this.

Comment: Can you please provide a screen shot of the constraints that you have given on storyboard ? It will help us to help you.

Comment: @MGP I tried to screen shot the constraints but I don't have enough points to post more than 2. I described them in text exactly as they appear in XCode.

Comment: Are you using the Size Classes or not ? and Please make sure the any other constraints are given to the button or not.

Comment: @robmayoff, here is a link to a new, separate project that I tried recreating the issue. In this test project, the button is not showing on screen before suddenly fading in at the correct position. The actual button in the other project appears up and to the right, then fades out and fades in at the correct lower + centered position.

https://bitbucket.org/innovative_software/ios-test-button

Comment: @MGP, "Use Autolayout" and "Use Size Classes" were checked by default. I'm using the latest stable XCode (7.x) and the simulator and my iPad are iOS 9.

Comment: The constraints gives in that project are correct and working fine as aspected. Try this close XCode, then open XCode, clean project, delete derived data and then run project. This may help you...!!

Comment: @MGP, what is delete derived data? Is that uninstalling the app from the simulator/device? I'm not familiar with that term.

Comment: Don't go for deleting derived data, try quitting Xcode once.

Comment: To delete derived: data Go to Window menu -> Select Projects -> Press delete button. And also delete app from simulator.

Comment: I have tried you project, and its working as you are expecting. Just Quit Xcode launch again and deep clean once, Command+Alt+Shift + k.

Comment: @MGP, nope. I did your steps to clean, delete derived, delete app from simulator. The button still appears on the right, then fades out, then fades in at the bottom (where it should always be due to the constraints).  Oddly enough, it appears on the right when it is launched, then just after XCode says "attached to process" it is moved to the correct position.

Comment: Try doing these steps: 1. Clear constraints and run the app. (See the position of the button). 2. Set VerticalCentre constraint, run the app and see the results. Try setting constraints one by one and see the result.

Comment: @budd I have checked your project and its constraints are fine. but please make sure that you does not manipulating constraints of button programatically. (In uploaded project you are not doing.). And one more thing are you tried to run that uploaded project b'coz it is running fine.

Comment: @MGP, yes I was not able to perfectly show the problem in the sample I uploaded--its the same constraints and position of the button but that one is working fine. There is NO code I've written to move the button.

Comment: @MGP, I deleted the button but it still shows on the right when app is launched and then disappears completely as it should since I deleted the button entirely. What is the reference still held?

Comment: I think I can help you out if u post the exact problem in your project ?

Comment: MGP, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Just add two constraints BottomSpace and CentreX as below. (And if required explicit height and width)

[image]

Comment: I already have these same constraints (see text of my question) except the bottom space is 100 instead of 50. (I chose an arbitrary number).

Answer (score 0):

1.Also provide button.left. 
Or
2. Use constraints show in image.

[image: constraints]

Comment: It is not required to give the button.left constraint. The given constraints is enough to position the button.

Comment: But in image you can see that the button moves right.

Comment: If you give a left constraint to button then it will placed different position on different devices (As per device width). It will not positioned properly at middle.

Comment: Use the size class. Just apply two constraints horizontally in container and vertically in container. Posted snap in my edited ans

Comment: @DhruvKhatri, I have the horizontal in container constraint, but I do NOT want it centered vertically in the container, as i have a different view above.

Comment: Put the button where you want to put and apply update constraints. In the last menu. It will not set the button at center but it will set center where your button is

Answer (score 0):

OK, I fixed the issue. Somehow, the splash screen storyboard got a copy of the button and other views that i had on the main storyboard. Once I deleted the button from the splash screen story board, the button issue stopped.

Apparently the first screen shot was the splash screen, and the second screen shot was the actual app (main storyboard).

Thanks to everyone for trying to help!